# Is $(1+c^2)^n-\lfloor(1+c^2)^{n/2}\rfloor^2<(1+c^2)^{(n+1)/2}$ true for all integers $c>1$, when $n$ is an odd integer?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Let $n$ be an odd integer. Is $$(1+c^2)^n-\lfloor(1+c^2)^{n/2}\rfloor^2<(1+c^2)^{(n+1)/2}$$ true for all integers $c>1$?

**Notes:**

- $c=1$ has a counterexample $2^{31}-\lfloor2^{31/2}\rfloor^2>2^{16}$; there are probably infinitely many of these. No counterexamples have been found for $(c,(n-1)/2)\in[2,20]\times[1,50]$.
- The bounds $x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x+1$ are too weak to prove anything non-trivial. This is because we are looking for a Diophantine approximation of half-integer powers of $1+c^2$ to an integer, and this doesn't seem straightforward at all.
- This inequality comes from an attempt to [bound the difference $|b-a|$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422749/113397) when an integer can be represented as $a^2+b^2$ in more than one way. It turns out that this is a very difficult thing to do, as we need to know and there is only a paucity of literature on the irrationality measure involving inverse trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd argue that it is still possible to do via $\lfloor x\rfloor\geq x-1$:
$$\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{n}-\lfloor\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor^{2}\leq\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1\right)^{2}$$
Expand the RHS to get:
$$\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1\right)^{2}=2\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1<2\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
And since $c\geq 2$, $\sqrt{c^2+1}\geq\sqrt5>2$:
$$2\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}<\sqrt{c^2+1}\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=2\left(1+c^{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$$
Unless, I am not understanding the problem correctly. I don't think the part mentioning that $c$ is odd was even nessacary for this argument. I did check this graphically and there are counterexamples, only for $c=1$ though, as only for $c=1$ is $\sqrt{c^2+1}<2$

Comment: Yeah, nice. I did exactly this before posting the question but upon second thought I mistakenly assumed I used the wrong direction of inequality. Sometimes elementary algebra can go beyond me :)